# Extracting unicode text from Excel spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

We generate HTML from text in an Excel spreadsheet.  The text contains unicode representations of international characters.  When we use VBA to extract the text and output it to a file, it is written as ANSI (ASCII).  Is there a way to preserve the unicode representation using VBA?

Bruce

Comment: VBA uses Unicode internally, so there shouldn't be any problem doing this in theory... can you insert a bit of the code you're using please? Especially the bit where you're writing the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default file writing mechanisms in VBA are ANSI ([just like VB6](http://www.i18nwithvb.com/chapters/Chapter06_en.htm)).

You need to use a different method. One [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016326/unicode-string-to-flat-file-from-vba/1019609#1019609) is to use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(VS.85).aspx).

```
   Dim fso As Object, MyFile As Object
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", False,True) 'Unicode=True'
   MyFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
   MyFile.Close
```