# Read Cyrillic characters to VBA variable

Tags: string, vba, encoding, cyrillic

I would like to read value from Excel cell containing Russian characters to VBA string variable or variant variable (for matrix). Suppose in `A1` cell we have Russian characters (displayed properly).

When I read it as `MyString=Range("A1").Value` the variable `MyString` reads as `?????????????????????????????????150???50`

Simmilarly this test fails:

```
? Activecell.Value
```

When I dump string to file with this code:

```
Dim myFile As String
Dim N As Integer
N = FreeFile()
myFile = "C:\MyFileName.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #N
Print #N, SQL
Close #N
Debug.Print myFile
```

I get `?????`

Comment: The VBA console does not support outputting Unicode characters. That does not mean they are broken. Output them to another cell - it should work as expected.

Comment: @Tomalak to another cell maybe yes. But I have to keep them in variant variable and then in string variable. When I send such a string variable with ADO to server or dump it (`Print #N, MyString`) to a text file I have `?????`.

Comment: *How* do you dump them to a file?

Comment: @Tomalak I updated my question.

Comment: Use a TextStream object to save the file. It has a Unicode option. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016326/unicode-string-to-flat-file-from-vba

Comment: Go to your regional settings `Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Region and Language`, select `Administrative` tab, click `Change system locale` in the `Language for non-Unicode programs`. Change that to whatever language you're using (other than English), then restart your PC (required!). This is to supply the correct characters with codes>=128 in the ASCII table (that's how languages were set in the pre-Unicode era). Should fix it.

Comment: This works for me - "When you copy and paste your VBA check if the Cyrillic characters are shown correctly - if not before pressing Ctrl + C to copy, change your language from English to your local Cyrillic language (sounds crazy but at my case this was the reason)"

Comment: If comments could be accepted as answers, I would accept Tomalak comments. "Use a TextStream object to save the file. It has a Unicode option. See" https://stackoverflow.com/q/1016326/1903793

Answer (score 2):

1. read the cells in a NOT type variable (because its UTF-8)
2. save the variable by using ADODB.stream (bytes not strings)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for Cyrillic VBA.

To solve it:

1st. Go to Regional and Language options Administrative -> Curent Language for non-Unicode programs - and choose your cyrillic language.

2nd. In excel - enter the VBA ( Alt +F11) choose tools -> Options -> Editor Format - and choose Font - Times New Roman (Cyrillic)

If the problem still occures - check if you're using a newer version on Excel ( my file was .xlxm so I save it as .xlsx and then create a new module (copy paste the VBA) and it worked.

When you copy and paste your VBA check if the Cyrillic characters are shown correctly - if not before pressing Ctrl + C to copy, change your language from English to your local Cyrillic language (sounds crazy but at my case this was the reason)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. My problem was not to read a value within the code but to read it with my eyes. It is actual for Microsoft Visual Basic 6.5 version 1057 (Office Tab Enterprise v8.00). Any Cyrillic font would fit.